# Google Analytics AMP Tracking

Tags: analytics, tracking, amp-html

We checked the possibility to track AMP and non-AMP users via amp-analytics, custom dimension etc.
Can anyone tell me, if it’s working in Safari meanwhile? We had some issues with 3rd party cookies and couldn’t track Safari users in AMP and analytics.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean [AMP Client ID](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/7486764) to track Analytics across AMP and Canonical Version?